# CSS - I need to move some text so that text flows around an image

Tags: css

I have an image that is positioned way over to the right side of the div. I want the text that is now being pushed below the image to rise up and wrap around the image, or ignore the image.

I've tried different floats and divs and wraps and overflows and all kinds of stuff but I can't get that text two rise up and fill the top left side of the box.

The image I am referring to is the "little red triangle" on right side of the page, in the very top box. There's only one of them.

Can you help me move that text into its proper place?

http://www.i-treadmillreviews.com/?1/treadmill-reviews-yowza

Comment: that image is for style, it should be added via a stylesheet.

Comment: +1 that. You should set it as a `background-image` and then use `background-position` to move it about.

Comment: I'll work on that right now. That's exactly the way I have most of the other images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is change the position to absolute class sale and make the parent div position: relative;

```
.PromoDiv {position: relative;}
.Sale {
position: absolute;
top: -6px;
left: 155px;
}
```

Comment: I thought your answer was pretty dumb and would never work. I tried it and it was perfect.  Once again, I learned something big by asking.  Thanks for you awesome help!!!

Comment: And just to be clear, I didn't think you were dumb, I just thought your solution wouldn't work. It was too simple. Again, much thanks.

Comment: No offence taken. A lot of times it's the simplest solutions that work best. Cheers